# How to remove an element from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array as below

```
var array = [];

var item1 = 'k1';
var itemvalue1 = {'key1':'value1'};
array[item1] = itemvalue1;

var item2 = 'k2';
var itemvalue2 = {'key2':'value2'};
array[item2] = itemvalue2;
```

Two questions...

1. How to get the position(index) of the  item2 in the array
2. How to remove the item item2 from the array

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An array has keys that are numerical and ordered, not strings. If you want those, use an object instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Riyas is a PHP programmer. There are no associative array in JavaScript... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get the position(index) of the item2 in the array

It doesn't have one.

You assigned the value to a property called `k2`. That isn't a numeric index, so it doesn't have a position.

You almost certainly should be using a plain object (`{}`) and not an array in the first place.

> How to remove the item item2 from the array

```
delete array.k2
```

(as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)).

Comment: i think `array.k2` will be undefined! array will be empty

Comment: @PriyeshKumar — You think wrong! http://jsbin.com/dovilom/1/edit?js,console

Comment: ohh, I was checking array.item  :)